# Azure DevOps pipeline - Push automatically a branch from a repository into another one

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, git-fork, git-mirror

I have a repository that's been forked several times and will continue to evolve. In the central repository, I have a release branch on which I merge when I want to deploy new features or bug fixes.
In each fork, I have a factory-update branch that needs to be updated automatically when I push something onto the release branch of the central repository.
[image: schema]

As I'm not used to make pipelines with Azure, I'm not sure on which way I should go. Add a remote branch from the central repository into each fork? But then how can I ensure the fetch of changes in every forks?
Or should I push my release branch in every forks? But I don't know how can I achieve that.

If someone has an example of yaml pipeline that does this kind of operation, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How do you intend to address merge conflicts when pushing to your forks? Presumably those forks are continuing to evolve independently.

Comment: Only a specific file will evolve on the forks, and modifications on this file are ignored and not pushed on the central repository. So merge conflicts are not supposed to happen.